# Canvas with text supporting native ctrl+f in browser

Tags: html5-canvas

Is it possible to somehow make "find" (ctrl+f) work if you are writing text inside a Canvas?

I checked out the basic examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text and when searching for "hello world" in chrome the canvas text is not hilighted.

Is there anyway of doing this?

If there isn't, has anyone seen an implementation of a "box-and-lines" chart (like UML) only using the DOM? (since then native find text would be supported)

Comment: Html5 Canvas paints text on its canvas -- *the text you see is an inaccessible set of pixels arranged in the shape of letters*, so Ctrl-f will not find the text. If you want searchable text you can use CSS to place html divs over the canvas and set their content to your desired text. Then Ctrl-f will find it. You can set `pointer-events: none` on the div so it doesn't catch events you intend for the canvas.

Comment: One wild (and not recommended) workaround is to put an element off-screen containing all your text. When Ctrl-f finds something in that element, you can fetch the selected text and calculate where you painted that same selected text on the canvas. Then you can redraw the selected text on the canvas as white-on-blue text to indicate that it was "found". This wild workaround is totally not recommended, but it would probably work.

Comment: Of some relevance to this: The next beta release of RGraph (www.rgraph.net) will support using DOM text instead of canvas text. An example URL is http://www.rgraph.net/demos/bar-basic.html (not currently - when I release the next beta).

Comment: @markE type your comments in an answer and I'll accept? :)

Comment: @Cotton. Done! BTW, did you end up going with my wild-and-crazy suggestion ... or something else?

Comment: @markE cool! I did some reading and realized svg was a better fit for my "box-and-line" diagram needs. But svgs handling of multiline overflowing text was bad so I ended up using SVG for drawing lines and absolute-positioned divs for boxes (as you suggested :) ). I put divs as contentEditable and so they automatically resize when you write text. Rudimentary demo if you want to try: https://docku.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html5 Canvas paints text on its canvas -- the text you see is an inaccessible set of pixels arranged in the shape of letters, so Ctrl-f will not find the text. If you want searchable text you can use CSS to place html divs over the canvas and set their content to your desired text. Then Ctrl-f will find it. You can set `pointer-events: none` on the div so it doesn't catch events you intend for the canvas.

One wild (and not recommended) workaround is to put an element off-screen containing all your text. When Ctrl-f finds something in that element, you can fetch the selected text and calculate where you painted that same selected text on the canvas. Then you can redraw the selected text on the canvas as white-on-blue text to indicate that it was "found". This wild workaround is totally not recommended, but it would probably work